# Why am I unable to change values of a Mongoose object to a different type ‘directly’?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've just spent a good hour figuring out something mind-boggling (at least to me, as a JS noob) and I'd like to understand the underlying logic (or just why it works this way, because I think it's illogical and quite unexpected).

Suppose I'm using Mongoose to retrieve documents from a database, some or all of which include a date property (created with `new Date()`), a numeric property, and a string property.

```
[{
  string: 'foo',
  date: '2018-10-13T21:11:39.244Z',
  number: 10
},
...
{
  string: 'bar',
  date: '2018-10-13T21:12:39.244Z',
  number: 20
}]
```

I thus obtain an array of objects and now want to take the date property for each object and change the value to a string, so I do something like:

```
doc.find({}, (err, list) => {
  list.forEach((item, index) => {
    list[index].date = 'new value'
  })
})
```

**But I can't do that!**

I **can** do `list[index].string = 'new value'` as well as `list[index].date = new Date()` but I **can't** change values that are of a different type, in this example `date` and `number`.

However, when I do `list[index]._doc.date = 'new value'`, which took so long to figure out because I didn't know Mongoose objects weren't just plain old objects and focused on solving problems I didn't have instead, I can modify the value just fine.

It appears that the mongoose object somehow translates `obj.key` to `obj._doc.key` only if the type of the value matches but I'd appreciate a more detailed explanation than my uneducated guesses.

Comment: Use aggregation here `db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": { "date": { "$dateToString": { "dateString": "$date" }}}}
])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to use multi type on a document field, Mongoose support this by "Mixed" type when you define the Schema.

You can get more detail from https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed.